# yet another rewriterule issue: adding a parameter to all URI without changing them

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite

- www.mydomain.com/www/whatever.php

to

- www.mydomain.com/www/whatever.php?hl=EN

whatever.php is not fixed, it represents any php page in the www directory.

my htaccess looks like this at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hl=
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1?hl=EN [QSA,R=301,L]
```

But for some reason it adds the real harddrive path of each page to www.mydomain.com, for example:

- 127.0.0.1:8080/index.php

becomes

- 127.0.0.1:8080/D:/mypath/index.php?hl=EN

I must be doing something wrong here, any idea?

Comment: I think your condition should check %{QUERY_STRING}  not REQUEST_URI. I'm not sure what you mean by the hard drive URL. Can you specify the original URL and the URL it's redirected to?

Comment: I added details, and corrected the `{QUERY_STRING}` thing

Comment: Strange. The regex match in RewriteRule will only match the REQUEST_URI part (eg. /my/little/pony/index.php). How is the environment you're working in? Localhost? Accessing the file directly with the file system path in the URL?

Comment: that's what I thought too...

Comment: How is your RewriteBase defined?

Comment: i didn't define any, should I?

Comment: I'm not sure. If this is in a `Directory` you might need one, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(www/[^.]+\.php)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*         %1?h1-EN             [R=301,L]
```

Redirects permanently

`http://www.mydomain.com/www/whatever.php` with or without trailing slash

To:

`http://www.mydomain.com/www/whatever.php?hl=EN`

All string are assumed to be fixed, except `whatever`.

For silent mapping, replace `[R=301,L]` with `[L]`

---

Edit From SO:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !hl=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(www/[^.]+\.php)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*         %1?hl=EN             [R=301,L]
```

did the trick, thanks

Comment: it worked, thanks!! One more thing, the url is redirected but I can't *see* the parameter added in the url, even by removing the R=301 thing. do you know how I could have the hl parameter in the url as if it were a GET parameter?

Comment: also, the rewritebase is optional, it was not necessary

Comment: I don't understand how h1-EN adds hl=EN to the url, any documentation refering to this?

Comment: First, let me understand what is happening. Is the substitution URL like this `http://www.mydomain.com/www/whatever.php?hl=EN` as in my answer or there is something missing?

Comment: no, and I'm realizing that actually the rewriterule is not working, it does not 'match' the uri. I'm going to revise it

Comment: holy oined sanctified crap, chrome is caching the http requests, it ruined all my tests. Getting good results now...

Comment: @Sebas  That's right. The script exists so the condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` shouldn't be there. Glad I could be of any help, anyway.